# Can functions referring to a Connected Google Sheet auto-update?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm using a Google Sheet connected to BigQuery, and have called functions on it (e.g. `=SUM('Connected sheet 1'!col_2)`).

I have added parameters to the query based off of a data validation cell, so when I change this cell I am finding that the Sheets do not update, nor does the function.

The custom SQL I have in the connected sheet is:

```
SELECT @PARAM AS col_1, 1 AS col_2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'b' AS col_1, 2 AS col_2
UNION ALL
SELECT 'c' AS col_1, 3 AS col_2
```

@PARAM is reading from a data validation cell.

Is there any way to get these to auto-update on changing this parameter?

Thanks in advance!

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Answer

***Unfortunately, you can’t automatically update your data***

There is only one option to setup a scheduled refresh and set the **Frequency** and **Between** parameters, you can schedule a Frequency of day, week or month between an specific range of time using the BigQuery tool.

### Details

In your BigQuery tool go to **Refresh options > Setup now** and define your scheduled refresh.

### Reference

[Analyze & refresh BigQuery data in Google Sheets using Connected Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/9703214)

Comment: Yes that all makes sense. Thanks for that clear and concise answer Jose.